# Tricking a collection with type erasure

Tags: java, casting, type-erasure

I was trying to illustrate type erasure to explain it to someone, but I found something unexpected. Here is the snippet I tried :

```
Object o = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> list = (List<String>) o;
list.add("Oups");
System.out.println(list);
```

I had expected this to throw a `ClassCastException` (or something similar) on the last line, but it did not. I also tried to populate the `ArrayList` with integer values before the casting to `Object`, and the result was the same.

Why is this different from

```
Integer[] arr0 = { 1,2,3,4 };
Object[] arr1 = arr0;
arr1[3] = "hey";
```

which **does** throw an exception (`ArrayStoreException`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated because of changes to the question.)

Your last line doesn't throw an exception simply because the `toString()` implementation of `ArrayList` doesn't care about the element type at all. It, simply, recursively calls `toString()` on every object stored in its internal `Object[]` array of elements, so there is never a need to check the runtime type of its elements.

However, this code would actually also not fail:

```
List<Integer> il = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Object o = il;
List<String> sl = (List<String>)o;
sl.add("Oups");
System.out.println(il.get(0));
```

This is because the argument type to `System.out.println` is `Object`, and therefore the compiler optimizes away the implicit cast to `Integer` at the point of `get()`, since it is not strictly "necessary". One may or may not argue that this is bad of the compiler since an early cast would detect errors earlier, but it is what it is.

On the other hand, replacing the last line with this *would* throw an exception:

```
System.out.println(il.get(0) + 5);
```

Because now you're carrying out an operation which assumes the element to be an `Integer`, and the cast is included in the generated code.

Primitive arrays, on the other hand, have run-time knowledge of their element type and will assert it on every insertion.

Comment: I should have included the real last line then, which was a print of the list. I'll update my post. Why printing the list does not result in an exception to be thrown ?

Comment: The addition of that "real last line" clearly made the question quite different, so I revised the answer completely. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of type-erasure at run-time it's of type `Object` anyway and your `List` is empty, and you never iterate it

```
List<Integer> o = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> list = (List<String>) (Object) o;
list.add("Oups");
for (Integer i : o) { // <-- Iterate the List<Integer>
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Will throw (at run-time)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: I also tried with a populated `List<Integer>`, forgot to mention it

Comment: Read about [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Haha I've already read this part of the documentation as there are many questions on it on SO but it seems I had memorized that the casting would not throw an exception in that case whereas the insertion would. I get now that this was a confusion between the arrays and generics, because `Integer[]` and `String[]` are actually two different classes whereas `List<Integer>` and `List<String>` aren't, at least in Java

Comment: @Dici For the array case, I can refer you to [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) and point out that arrays extend `Object` (they are instances).

Answer (score 1):

The array inside the `ArrayList` is an `Object[]`, not an `Integer`, so there's no problem assigning any arbitrary object to it. It'll break when you try to execute `list.get(0)`, because the compiler will insert an implicit cast, `(Integer) list.get(0)`, which will fail.

(This is one of the reasons heap pollution is a nasty bug; the failure can happen somewhere far removed from the code that's actually buggy.)